# String Delimiter in Python

Tags: python

I want to do split a string using `"},{"` as the delimiter. I have tried various things but none of them work.

```
string="2,1,6,4,5,1},{8,1,4,9,6,6,7,0},{6,1,2,3,9},{2,3,5,4,3 "
```

Split it into something like this:

```
2,1,6,4,5,1
8,1,4,9,6,6,7,0
6,1,2,3,9
2,3,5,4,3
```

`string.split("},{")` works at the Python console but if I write a Python script in which do this operation it does not work.

Comment: It does not make sense that it works on the console but not in a script. How does your script look like?

Comment: on a python console

>>>string="{{2,4,5},{1,9,4,8,6,6,7},{1,2,3},{2,3}}"

>>>string.split("},{")

even replace works fine but when but the same thing in a script it does not


def convert2list(string):
        string=string.strip()
        string=string[2:len(string)-2].split("},{")

Comment: Make sure your function returns a value, not just assign it to something.  Also, if you want the output to actually appear on the screen, you need to call 'print'

Answer (score 12):

You need to assign the result of `string.split("},{")` to a new string. For example:

```
string2 = string.split("},{")
```

I think that is the reason you think it works at the console but not in scripts. In the console it just prints out the return value, but in the script you want to make sure you use the returned value.

Comment: Right answer, although string2 may be a bad variable name considering it is a list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return` the string back to the caller. Assigning to the `string` parameter doesn't change the caller's variable, so those changes are lost.

```
def convert2list(string):
    string = string.strip()
    string = string[2:len(string)-2].split("},{")

    # Return to caller.
    return string

# Grab return value.
converted = convert2list("{1,2},{3,4}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in steps:

1. Split at commas to get "{...}" strings.
2. Remove leading and trailing curly braces.

It might not be the most Pythonic or efficient, but it's general and doable.

Answer (score 0):

I was taking the input from the console in the form of arguments to the script....

So when I was taking the input as {{2,4,5},{1,9,4,8,6,6,7},{1,2,3},{2,3}} it was not coming properly in the arg[1] .. so the split was basically splitting on an empty string ...

Answer (score 0):

If I run the below code from a script file (in Python 2.7):

> string="2,1,6,4,5,1},{8,1,4,9,6,6,7,0},{6,1,2,3,9},{2,3,5,4,3 "
>
> print string.split("},{")

Then the output I got is:

> ['2,1,6,4,5,1', '8,1,4,9,6,6,7,0', '6,1,2,3,9', '2,3,5,4,3 ']

And the below code also works fine:

```
string="2,1,6,4,5,1},{8,1,4,9,6,6,7,0},{6,1,2,3,9},{2,3,5,4,3 "
def convert2list(string):
    string=string.strip()
    string=string[:len(string)].split("},{")
    print string
convert2list(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This:
This will split the string considering **},{** as a delimiter and print the list with line breaks.

```
string = "2,1,6,4,5,1},{8,1,4,9,6,6,7,0},{6,1,2,3,9},{2,3,5,4,3"
for each in string.split('},{'):
    print each
```

Output:

```
2,1,6,4,5,1
8,1,4,9,6,6,7,0
6,1,2,3,9
2,3,5,4,3
```

If you want to print the split items in the list only you can use this simple print option.

```
string = "2,1,6,4,5,1},{8,1,4,9,6,6,7,0},{6,1,2,3,9},{2,3,5,4,3"
print string.split('},{')
```

Output:

```
['2,1,6,4,5,1', '8,1,4,9,6,6,7,0', '6,1,2,3,9', '2,3,5,4,3']
```

Comment: please add sample input and output. It will help in better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply ,you have to use split() method ,and "},{" as a delimeter, then print according to arguments (because string will be a list ) ,
like the following :

```
string.split("},{")
for i in range(0,len(string)):
    print(string[i])
```