# Unable to parse a number to be used within a link

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to get the value of `Tax District` from a webpage. In it's main page there is a form to fill in to generate the result in which the information i'm looking for is available. When I use my script below, I get the desired result but the thing is I had to use different link to parse the result. The link I used within my script is available only when the form is filled in. The newly generated link (which I've used within my script) has some number which I can't figure out how to find that.

[Main link](https://wedge.hcauditor.org/)

In the search form there is a radio button `Street Address` which is selected by default. Then:-

```
house number: 5587 (just above Exact/Low)
street name: Surrey
```

> This is the link `https://wedge.hcauditor.org/view/re/5500171005200/2018/summary` generating automatically which has some number `5500171005200` within it.

I've written the following script to get the result but really don't know how the number in that url generates as the number changes when I use different search terms:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://wedge.hcauditor.org/view/re/5500171005200/2018/summary'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
item = soup.select_one("div:contains('Tax District') + div").text
print(item)
```

***How can I get the number used within the newly generated link?***

Comment: Could you read in the URL and then use [delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272784/string-delimiter-in-python) to split the string into pieces (Perhaps use '/'). Then iterate through searching for a string that is an int (using the [str.isDigit() function](https://tdhopper.com/blog/testing-whether-a-python-string-contains-an-integer/)). The only downside to this is it appears the year is also in the URL, so you will have to do some logic for removing that or find a different delimiter.

Comment: Did you have scope to go through the description I've provided above @plum 0? It is not about parsing the number from a known link. That link generates only when a search form is duly filled in. Thanks.

Comment: So you are filling in the search form and not retrieving the next link... My apologies that you have hardcoded in the link for your example to us in your program thus leading me to believe you could access the URL you retrieve from the search and you wanted to do more information with the number. Also that number is the parcel-id, figure out how to get that information and you have your answer. Alternatively find a way to click the search button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems a POST and GET is fine. No need to look for that other number. I use Session to pass cookies. The link you reference however is found within the GET response.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

data = {
    'search_type': 'Address',
    'sort_column': 'Address',
    'site_house_number_low':5587,
    'site_house_number_high':'',
    'site_street_name': 'surrey'  
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post('https://wedge.hcauditor.org/execute', data = data)
    r = s.get('https://wedge.hcauditor.org/view_result/0')
    soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
    print(soup.select_one('.label + div').text)
```

---

You can see the details and sequence captured in the web traffic. I happened to use fiddler here.

[image]

Comment: I see!! It's really hard to capture that in chrome dev tools as it shows up and vanishes instantly.

Comment: yup. That is why I usually use at least two tools for web traffic.

Comment: One last question for clarity of things: what made you think to use this specific url subsequesntly `https://wedge.hcauditor.org/view_result/0` as there were other urls (in dev tools) within different get requests as well @QHarr. Thanks in advance.

Comment: because the first is the POST and then the second states view_result in the url as well as being the next bit of traffic. fiddler allows you to filter sessions on those containing some text/number so I input your number to verify.